# Display Custom Taxonomies under Custom post types

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I'm a newbie in WordPress. I have created a custom post type called `arts` and custom taxonomies called `male`, `female` and `children` for `arts`. Is there a way I could list only the taxonomies under the post type `arts`? I have tried using `get_taxonomies();` but it produces all the taxonomies but I want only taxonomies under `arts`. My code is here. Thanks.

```
<?php $taxonomies=get_taxonomies(); 

var_dump($taxonomies);

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me know if this works for u --

```
<?php 
$args=array(
  'name' => 'arts'
);
$output = 'objects'; // or objects
$taxonomies=get_taxonomies($args,$output); 
if  ($taxonomies) {
  foreach ($taxonomies  as $taxonomy ) {
    echo '<p>' . $taxonomy->name . '</p>';
  }
}  
?>
```

**Reference** - [Source](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_taxonomies)

Comment: @Ukavi echo "<pre>"; print_r($taxonomies); and let me know what exactly is outputting ?

Comment: It's outputting an empty array

Answer (score 0):

I think you will want to use this function and pass the custom post type as a parameter.

```
$taxonomies=get_object_taxonomies('arts');
```